# How to fix "Access to database denied" when accessing PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, server

I got a tiny problem regarding connection to my server. What should we do when this message appears in front of you?

[image]

I've done several changes in the ***pg_hba.conf*** entry but yet to succeed. Any careless mistake from my side?

Comment: Migrate this to SuperUser?

Comment: @zearth are you intending to use postgis with postgres - if yes it is a GIS related question.

Comment: @Mapperz Of course.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you network is secure:

```
# Allow a user from host 192.168.0.100 to connect to database
# "postgres" if the user's password is correctly supplied.
# 
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        IP-ADDRESS          METHOD
host    postgres    all         192.168.0.100          md5
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html#EXAMPLE-PG-HBA.CONF

Comment: With that format, an `IP-mask` must follow the `IP-ADDRESS`. Or you could just use a single `CIDR-address` of `192.168.0.100/32`.

Answer (score 3):

If you make any changes to the configuration files (most notably `pg_hba.conf`), you need to signal the database server to **reload**. If your database server is on a Windows computer, this is likely in the start menu:

Start > PostgreSQL 9.0 > Reload Configuration

or if it is on a POSIX system (Linux, Mac OS X, etc.), the direct way is with [pg_ctl reload [-s] [-D datadir]](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-pg-ctl.html), or some other convenient service wrapper, e.g. if you install via YUM from http://www.pgrpms.org/:

```
service postgresql-9.0 reload
```

The result from either Windows or POSIX reload should show a helpful message, like:

> server signaled

If there are problems with your `pg_hba.conf` file, they should appear here.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the pg_hba.conf settings, you may want to look at listen_addresses from your postgresql.conf file.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html

Comment: but the message above shows that the database is listening to (and rejecting) connections

Comment: start using the "trust" method which should allow you to connect no matter what and then work your way up. Can you connect locally with **host all   all  127.0.0.1/32  trust** ?

Answer (score 1):

I went through similar problem. I was able to fix it by editing the pg_hba.config file and adding another entry immediately after the default one for the remote machine ipaddress range. I basically copied the default one and just changed the database, user, CIDR-ADDRESS and METHOD information. I reloaded the config file from start menu (start/postgres x.x/reload configuration). This solved my problem.
like this:

## IPv4 local connections:

host     all     all     ***.0.0.*/32    trust (default one)

## IPv4 local connections:

host     zigag   gisuser     172.05.003.12/32    trust